# How can the qbposxml API version 3.0 DTD be used by the 3.0 SDK QBWC?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I am using the Quickbooks POS (qbposxml) API via the Quickbook WebConnector (QBWC).

I am using the QBWC version from the 3.0 SDK, and i'm attempting to send messages and receive responses that include elements > the version 1.0 DTD.

I am able to successfully send/receive version 3.0 messages using the SDKTest.exe tool when i prefix the XML with the version processing instruction...

```
<?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
```

But when i send the same message via the QBWC it does not seem to recognize the version processing instruction and only uses the 1.0 DTD?

Here is a clip of the verbose QBWC log demonstrating the calls and responses.
http://pastebin.com/fj3wqLuM

I am not sure what i am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using double quotes (") instead of single quote (')?

Comment: That was the answer!  Thanks William.